# Find the volume of $y=x^2$

Tags: calculus

Given $$y=x^2$$ , the x-axis and x=1

Find volume about x=-1.

If it's about x-axis then it's easy. But now it's x=-1. 
I tried $$\int^1_0 \pi (x^2-1 )^2dx $$ but I can't get the ans $2\pi^2$

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more precise. What volume are you after? What do you mean by 'given the x axis and x=1'?

Comment: Do you mean the volume of revolution?

Comment: Is this homework? Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @Shaun yes it is the volume of revolution. I just want to know when the question state the volume of revolution about x=-1 what do I do to my equation that I want to integrate.

Comment: @Fred: Try copying the entire question down here (if you can), giving a reference & page number, and/or telling us what you've learned already. I'm suggesting this because, at the moment, you're unclear.